# Additive analogy of proportionality symbol

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology

The relation of proportionality is quite abundant, and so for convenience there exist symbols, such as "$\propto$", to denote it. I would like to know if there is likewise a symbol to denote the additive analogy, i.e. the relation $A = B + c$ for some objects of interest $A$ and $B$, and some uninteresting object $c$.

Comment: You could interpret $O(\cdot)$ and $\Theta(\cdot)$ notation in such a way.

Comment: Can you give specific examples of the "symbols to denote it" for proportionality? Do you mean exact proportionality, or only approximate proportionality?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I mean exact proportionality ($\propto$) and have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Leibniz occasionally used the symbol ${}_{\ulcorner\!\urcorner\!}$ to denote a relation of approximate equality (up to an infinitesimal). This is discussed in more detail in [this recent article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10670-012-9370-y). One antecedent of Leibniz's idea is Fermat's [adequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adequality).

Similarly, in analysis with infinitesimals the exact relationship $\approx$ denotes the relation of "equality up to infinitesimal". For example, to calculate the derivative of $y=x^2$ one would take an infinitesimal $\Delta x$, compute the corresponding $\Delta y$, and form the quotient $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.  Simplifying the quotient one gets $2x+\Delta x$ and one concludes that $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx 2x$, given the exact formula for the derivative.

Comment: I intended to ask for a symbol to describe an exact relation, but as Thomas Andrews indicated, this was not quite clear. Also, I think your answer gave very interesting input, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard symbol.

If you really want to use symbols, then $A = B +c$ iff $e^A \propto e^B$, but this is hardly clear.